# How to remove properties from log entries in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog with ASP.Net Core 2.0, writing to RollingFile using JsonFormatter.
 Followed the instructions here to configure: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore.  
 Everything works great, but in every log entry I get the following properties that I did not log:

- SourceContext
- RequestId
- RequestPath

I presume they are being added by the ASP.Net Core logging framework. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be achieved by plugging an enricher into the logging pipeline:

```
.Enrich.With(new RemovePropertiesEnricher())
```

Where:

```
class RemovePropertiesEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent le, ILogEventPropertyFactory lepf)
    {
        le.RemovePropertyIfPresent("SourceContext");
        le.RemovePropertyIfPresent("RequestId");
        le.RemovePropertyIfPresent("RequestPath");
    }
}
```

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Not to hijack the post, but what and why are these injected automatically?

Comment: I had this very same question.

Somewhere early in the request pipeline, a [HostingLogScope](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/5543d29af1e6b4f2f5dfa8822db12b666f33d1b5/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingLoggerExtensions.cs) is created. As you can see from the source, this log scope is responsible for adding (most) of the offending properties. 

I'm missing a link for where it *exactly* happens, but Serilog then takes this context object and turns it into the properties of a log entry. Since the context is a IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string,object>>, it maps naturally

Comment: This doesn't work with the "Exception" field.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to remove the sub-property (a property of property) as well?

Comment: I'm wondering why the [JsonIgnore] attribute is not applied for this?

Comment: Does it work for nested fields? I think, no

Answer (score 3):

When you are logging an object, Serilog has the concept of [destructuring](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#preserving-object-structure).

And if you want to remove(ignore) some properties in those objects for logging, there are two options.

1. You can use attributes. Take a look at this [post](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/07/using-attributes-to-control-destructuring-in-serilog/).
2. Then there is [by-ignoring](https://github.com/destructurama/by-ignoring). You need this Destructurama.ByIgnoring [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Destructurama.ByIgnoring/).

Note you should not use both. Using both did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get rid of them. Try to use log template:

```
_loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(LogLevel.Debug, "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}");
```

In this scenario, you won't see mentioned properties in your output.

Comment: Thanks Leonid, my logging to console works fine. Because like in your example I have a message template there that does not contain these parameters. How to I get rid of them when logging to file: .WriteTo.RollingFile(new JsonFormatter(), logFilePath, LogEventLevel.Information)? I do not want to provide a template here, just want to log raw json.

Comment: Currently, this feature is not supported (I checked the source code). I see a workaround, you can use kind of template that forms JSON file. Or you can implement this feature and create a pull request to their repository.